# What movie opens with two scorpions fighting each other?

Tags: identify-this-movie

It is an **American** movie, **not older than 20 years**.

The opening credits is a **fight between two CGI scorpions**, I believe on a desert road. The opening credits end when one of the scorpions win, but then (I think) it is ran over by a car.  The scene I'm talking about is shown very close range and "filmed" in a way that makes it look like a giant monster fight. I do think they're also black and yellow, but I'm not sure.

I can't think of any connection between this scene and the rest of the movie, that's why I can't recall which movie it is. Google returned me documentaries about scorpions, *Mortal Kombat*, *The Scorpion King* and *Clash of Titans*. I'd appreciate the help.

**Edit:** So, a few things. Because the tone of the sequence was almost mockery, the movie is probably a **comedy** or cheap **action** flick. Definitely not a drama.
The scorpions are CG, but not very good. So probably from **late 90's early 2000's**.

I am fairly sure this takes place in a desert and the scorpion that wins is squashed by a car, so the only connection it has with the movie is someone driving to a city in a desert (maybe **Las Vegas**?).

Comment: There is a scorpion fight scene in jarhead, but I think its not what you looking for, just take a look at it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2scLhEdWwAU)

Comment: Yeah, that's not it. The scene I'm talking about is show very close range and "filmed" in a way that makes it look like a giant monster fight.
But I do think they're also black and yellow, but I'm not sure.
Deviating a little: those scorpions in Jarhead scene are also CG? Great looking for the time!

Comment: I kinda remember this but can't recall the film...What was the film actually *about*...who was in it.

Comment: Are you sure it's a movie and not [a computer game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnnGin60bXo)? There are several of those...

Comment: It's not a computer game. But yes, *any* additional info about the plot, characters, genre, tone etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Definitely not a video game.
I'm sorry I don't have more to go on. The thing is, it was so disconnected from the rest of the movie that I don't what movie it is. It was like the director said "hey, I got some leftover money; here, look at this CG sequence I could buy".

Comment: Yep, an apt description of that scene. :P Thanks for elaborating and possible match below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for [3000 Miles to Graceland](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0233142/combined) from 2001.

> It was an ingenious enough plan: rob the Riviera Casino's count room during an Elvis impersonator convention. But Thomas Murphy decided to keep all the money for himself and shot all his partners, including recently-freed ex-con Michael Zane. With $3.2 million at stake, the Marshals Service closing in, and single mom Cybil Waingrow and her son Jesse constantly confounding things, Michael must track down Murphy.

It stars Kurt Russell, Kevin Costner, Courteney Cox and many other known names and the movie begins with the exact CGI scorpion battle you described:

Comment: Ha! Exactly that one. I remember it not being a very good CG, but looking at it now, it is way worse than I remembered. I'll watch the movie again, see if there is connection with this bizarre opening that I missed. Thanks a lot!